# Return array result from query from function

Tags: php, oop, pdo

Hi all I'm new to oop and I wanted to find out how to return multiple array variable from a function. Please see below for an explanation

```
function getvalues(){
  //do mysql query using pdo
   while($row = $getmostvalues->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $value[] = $row['val1'];
        $time[] = $row['time'];

    }


}
```

how can I retrieve and use say $value[0] in my php code after calling getvalues();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're looking for an answer on doesn't have anything to do with OOP, but here's your answer. It's more of a question on how to use arrays.

```
function getvalues(){
    while($row = $getmostvalues->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $value[] = $row['val1'];
        $time[] = $row['time'];
    }

    return array($value,$time);
}

$retval = getvalues();
$arrValues = $retval[0];
$arrTimes = $retval[1];
```

Value at index of the values array would then be `$arrValues[0]`.

If you're trying to return an object:

`return (object) array('value' => $value, 'time' => $time);`

This would return an object with two arrays accessible via `$retval->value` and `$retval->time`

If you don't want arrays, cast those arrays as objects as well.

Comment: Is there a way to reference the values using the variable names instead of the index 0,1....

Comment: like arrTimes = $retval['time'] and also in your answer do you mean $retval[0] instead of $val[0]

Comment: You can cast the array to an object. `return (object) array($value,$time);`

Comment: I clarified my answer for you. You should edit your question if you still need help.